# Prove that $\sqrt{5}+1$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, radicals

I'm guessing this is pretty basic,

but I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you proved that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know if it's valid to say that if √5 is irrational, then √5+1 is also irrational.

Comment: If $\sqrt{5}+1$ were rational, then $(\sqrt{5}+1)-1$ would be rational too

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\sqrt{5}+1 = r$ for some rational $r$. The set of all rationals with the usual addition and multiplication is a field, implying that $r-1$ is rational; this shows that $\sqrt{5}$ is rational. Then by well-ordering principle there is a least integer $a$ such that $a\sqrt{5}$ is an integer; but $(\sqrt{5}-2)a < a$ is an integer such that $[(\sqrt{5}-2)a]\sqrt{5}$ is an integer, a contradiction; therefore, the number $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

Comment: Amazing proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{p}$, $p$ prime. +1

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**
Use proof by contradiction: Assume that $\sqrt{5} +1$ is *rational*.

Then $\sqrt{5} +1=\cfrac{p}{q}$ where $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{N^{+}}$.